# Why aren't my sprites (custom CG shader) drawn on a Unity rendertexture

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, alpha, render-to-texture, cg

I've a custom normal-mapped + specular sprite shader that works fine. However, when I try drawing onto a rendertexture, my sprites are invisible. I guess their alpha is set to 0 as other sprites using Unity's default shaders are drawn okay.

How can I fix this?

```
Shader "SG/_ShipSurfaceShader" {
Properties {
    _MainTex ("Main texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _NormalTex ("Normal map", 2D) = "bump" {}
    _SpecColor ("Specular colour", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
    _SpecPower ("Specular power", Range (0.0,2.0)) = 0.5
}
SubShader {
    Tags { "Queue"="Transparent" }
    Blend SrcAlpha OneMinusSrcAlpha
    LOD 200

    CGPROGRAM
    #pragma surface surf BlinnPhongTransparent alpha

    inline fixed4 LightingBlinnPhongTransparent (SurfaceOutput s, fixed3 lightDir, half3 viewDir, fixed atten) {
        half3 h = normalize (lightDir + viewDir);
        fixed diff = max (0, dot (s.Normal, lightDir));
        float nh = max (0, dot (s.Normal, h));
        float spec = pow (nh, s.Specular*32.0) * s.Gloss;
        fixed4 c;
        c.rgb = (s.Albedo * _LightColor0.rgb * diff + _LightColor0.rgb * _SpecColor.rgb * spec) * (atten);
        c.a = s.Alpha;
        return c;
    }

    sampler2D _MainTex;
    sampler2D _NormalTex;
    half _SpecPower;

    struct Input {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
    };

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
        fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex);
        o.Albedo = c.rgb;
        o.Alpha = c.a;
        o.Normal = UnpackNormal(tex2D (_NormalTex, IN.uv_MainTex));
        o.Specular = _SpecPower;
        o.Gloss = 1;
    }
    ENDCG
} 
FallBack "Diffuse"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** : So, i found problem!

```
#pragma surface surf BlinnPhongTransparent keepalpha // <= here
```

And i found other problem with "layers", maybe you know about this: first planet renders behind second planet, but in coordinates first closest to camera.

```
RT_lowres = new RenderTexture(width_rt, height_rt, 1, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);// if 0 bad "layers"
```

Some tip: You can use global variables in shaders to increase perfomance! lol

```
void Start(){
    //....
    lowresCam.targetTexture = RT_lowres;
    Shader.SetGlobalTexture("_LowResTexture", RT_lowres);
}

void OnRenderImage(RenderTexture src, RenderTexture dest){
    Graphics.Blit(src, dest, compositionMaterial);
}
```

In Shader:

```
Properties
{
    _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
}
//.....
sampler2D _MainTex;
sampler2D _LowResTexture;
fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
{
    //...
    fixed4 lowres = tex2D(_LowResTexture, i.uv);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Huge thanks. Still wrestling with rendertexture transparency so will let you know if I get this working, but shader works off the bat.

Comment: It hasn't worked. I've got two render targets being alpha-blended in a post effect, a background nebula at quarter res and the main camera with gameplay objects. 3D objects and conventional sprites are drawn, but my ship with your shader is invisible. And if I change the drawing of my ship to Unity's Mobile/Particles/Alpha Blended, it draws but without normal map lighting.

Comment: @DavidCoombes so, if you put this material on `SpriteRenderer` it will be work normally, Your ship is Visible in Scene and/or Camera? or what? Can you put some screensshots or draw some sсheme.  **This shader work on my project, but i dont know how it must work in yours.**

Comment: Two screenshots and a zipped project. I'm drawing the ship into a lowres buffer. Using your shader (or mine) the ship is invisible. Using the Uber Sprite Shader free from the Asset Store (https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/88191) the ship is drawn. IMAGE 1 : https://www.dropbox.com/s/4dh8lkrmgkxv94o/SO_1.jpg   IMAGE 2 : https://www.dropbox.com/s/vj0gnjgkk795rmm/SO_2.jpg   PROJECT : https://www.dropbox.com/s/htqbb1fgdm1uwxp/RT%20Test.zip?dl=0

Comment: @DavidCoombes Oh. You using `MeshRenderer` component, i don't know it. I thought otherwise and modificate your shader for `SpriteRenderer`! Test my shader with `SpriteReneder`.  I will soon rewrite my answer if you really want to use `MeshRenderer`.

Comment: @DavidCoombes Do you using `Light` (directional, spot, point lights) in game?

Comment: Yes, two directional lights that work with the normal maps. IIRC I used meshes because when I started this game years ago, normal mapped sprites weren't an option. I don't know the differences between Mesh and Sprite renderer to know if it matters. ;)

Comment: @DavidCoombes so, you can swap to `SpriteRenderer` it will be good choice for performance for 2d games.)

Comment: If I use a SpriteRenderer, all three shaders fail as "Material texture property _MainTex has offset/scale set. It is incompatible with SpriteRenderer."

Comment: @DavidCoombes did you test it, вшв нщг fixed the problem?

Comment: Not yet. I won't leave you hanging! Just need to find time.

Comment: You absolute star! Keepalpha is the trick. Thanks for the optimisation tip too.